# What is the use of uniqueidentifier in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
   Table1 (Table_ID Int Primary Key, Name Varchar(50), ROWID Uniqueidentifier)
```

and the default value for `ROWID` column is set using `NEWID()` function.

I understand that `NEWID()` function will generate a unique identifier for each row.

I am wondering why do we need a unique identifier for each row? If we want uniqueness for each and every row I can achieve that using my primary key. I am new to SQL. Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Let's say you have a bunch of different identical databases for different clients and then a central database that houses some information from all clients. If you need uniqueness on the table in the central database you can achieve this (for the most part) with UniqueIdentifier.

Comment: You would have to ask the original designer of this database schema about his reasons. Some features of SQL Server like replication do require a GUID column to function - maybe that was one of the reasons. But I would agree with you - if you already have a primary key, then yet another unique `ROWID` is really not necessary

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful if you're interfacing with other systems. However, if you're working in an isolated system, you can absolutely use your PK as the "unique" row id for the table.

Answer (score 0):

uniqueidentifier is a CPU specific ID, it is GLOBALLY UNIQUE, it's very useful especially if you ever have to move your data as row_identity (integer) would start over on new DB SERVER..